# error when encrypt and decrypt with aes in ruby using UTF-8

Tags: ruby, utf-8, aes

When I try to encrypt and decrypt in ruby, I have a problem whth encrypt and      decrypt

here is aescrypt.rb I use

```
 # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

 require 'openssl'
 require 'base64'

 module AESCrypt
   def self.encrypt(message, password)
     Base64.encode64(self.encrypt_data(message, self.key_digest(password),      nil, "AES-128-CBC"))
   end

   def self.decrypt(message, password)
     base64_decoded = Base64.decode64(message)
     self.decrypt_data(base64_decoded, self.key_digest(password), nil, "AES-     128-CBC")

   end

   def self.key_digest(password)
     OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new(password).digest
   end

   def self.decrypt_data(encrypted_data, key, iv, cipher_type)
     aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(cipher_type)
     aes.decrypt 'utf-8'

     iv = ("\0" * 16)

     aes.key = key
     aes.iv = iv
     aes.update(encrypted_data) + aes.final  
   end

   def self.encrypt_data(data, key, iv, cipher_type)
     aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(cipher_type)
     aes.encrypt 'utf-8'

     iv = ("\0" * 16)

     aes.key = key
     aes.iv = iv
     aes.update(data) + aes.final      
   end
 end
```

when I encrypt and decrypt the string 'abcde' using this code, it works properly
But the problem is using the other language like chinese, korean, japanese using this code

is there a problem of encoding with utf-8?

here is I used in my code that works

```
    <% temp1 = "12345" %>
    <% tempcenter = AESCrypt.encrypt(temp1,"rf") %>
    <% temp2 = AESCrypt.decrypt(tempcenter,"rf") %>
```

but when I change temp1 = "(chinese)" it goes wrong.
please help me

Comment: How does it go wrong? You might just need to set the encoding with [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) after base64 decoding. Also note that [`Cipher#encrypt`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-encrypt) and [`Cipher#decrypt`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-decrypt) don’t take any arguments.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my time!